# While loop doesn't stop with multiple conditions

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am new to coding and i wanted to make a code that could register people and log them back in. while working on my code i wanted to check if the user wanted to login or register so i made this code in python.

```
login_or_register = None
while login_or_register != 'login' or login_or_register != 'register':

 login_register = input('Would you like to login or register?')
 login_or_register = login_register.lower()
 login_or_register = login_register
```

While loop doesn't stop even if variable meets the conditions. I tried to remove the second condition and it started to work for some reason. 
This is probably a dumb question but please be patient I'm a high school student.

```
Would you like to login or register?login
Would you like to login or register?register
Would you like to login or register?keeps going :(
Would you like to login or register?
```

It is suppose to stop the loop when input is login or register. Output is suppose to be changing variable login_or_register = None to the answer.

Comment: Hi, Please provide what input you are giving to code and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of your loop cannot possibly become true.

`or` returns `True` if one or both of the two conditions becomes `True`.
If your input is `'login'`, the first condition is `False` and the second is `True`.

For `'register'` the first condition becomes `True` and the second `'False'`.

In all other cases both conditions are `True`. Therefore you have created an infinite loop.

A solution would be connecting the two conditions with an `and` or even better create a list with all allowed inputs and use an `in` to check if the user input is in that list. That will be more clear if you have more different options the user is allowed to enter.

For example:

```
login_or_register = None
while login_or_register not in ['login', 'register']:
    login_register = input('Would you like to login or register?')
    login_or_register = login_register.lower()
```

You may also want to take a look at [the python docs for `or` and `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or)

Answer (score 3):

`login_or_register != 'login' or login_or_register != 'register'` will always be True. You probably want to use a logical `and`:

```
while login_or_register != 'login' and login_or_register != 'register':
    # ....
```